# Can't add servlet in Eclipse Google App Engine project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm trying to add a servlet to a web application in Eclipse but I can't because I have to chose a project in the project selection dropdown list and there is no proposal in it :

[image]

The finish button stay disabled until a project is selected so I can't add my servlet.

Comment: Have you already created the project to which you want to add the servlet? Is this project open?

Comment: Yes, and i'm trying to add a new servlet bu right clicking on the project folder

Comment: When you created the project, did you just select 'Java Project'? Or did you select 'Dynamic Web Project'?

Comment: Servlets could only be added into projects that are defined as Dynamic Web Project within eclipse, are you sure that's what you opened?

Comment: My project is a google app engine web application

Comment: Did you open it independentl and imported it into eclispe as an existing project, or did you open it directly from eclipse

Comment: You don't have a Java EE project at all (*Dynamic Web Project* for example). Create one, or else simply manually create the servlet via *New Class*. Or, perhaps your GAE project plugin is broken.

Comment: I created it in Eclipse directly

Comment: So I'm assuming you have the proper google app engine plugin installed?, which version of eclipse are you using, and which plugin version are you using

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, When creating a new project that will contain servlets, you should create a Dynamic Web Project:

[image: create a Dynamic Web Project with the wizard]

If you've already created the project, you can right-click / Configure / Convert to Faceted Form / Dynamic Web Module.

Comment: But isn't it possible to add a servlet to a google app engine project @whistling_marmot ??

Comment: I've added a new answer specific to Google App Engine projects.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project, and click 'Properties'. Then open 'Project Facets', and tick the 'Dynamic Web Module' check-box.

[image]

After doing this, your project will be available in the Create Servlet wizard.