# eclipse error: Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints: Could not find web.xml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm seeing this weird error in eclipse:

[image: There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints: Could not find web.xml]

I am uncertain why I am getting this error because the web.xml file is exactly where it is supposed to be:

[image]

I am using:

- Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
- Google App Engine Plugin for Eclipse 4.4
- App Engine SDK 1.9.34

I've searched the web but I have not found anyone else experiencing this particular error.

This *might* be related to the fact that I had to manually turn on the "Dynamic Web Module" Project Facet in order to create new servlets.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35117141/2341218

**UPDATE:**

Turning the "Dynamic Web Module" Project Facet off for the project makes the error go away.

If you toggle it back on again, it seems to stay gone UNTIL you select to generate a new servlet via "File > New > Servlet".

This happens in the recently released
 - Google App Engine Plugin for Eclipse 4.5 (Mars)

[image]

Comment: Try changing the "Dynamic web module" to 2.5 version. Because appengine uses Java Servlet 2.5 standard [App engine runtime doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Java_Introduction)